# How do I add code behind a button in a Detail view Controller of a the Storyboard in a Visual Studio Xamarin.IOS project?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I want a button to update a text field in my app, which runs on an iPad.

I created a Xamarin.IOS master details project, and added a button and textfield. 
But can't find out to add the code behind that executes when button clicked.

In Visual Basic, I could just double-click the button and the event handling function (code behind) pops up.  Can't figure out how to do this in XAMARIN.

Comment: Is my answer make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

After you add a `button` or a `textfield` to the storyboard, you can select the button in the storyboard and then you can give it a name in the properties(right corner of visual studio), you can see the screenshot here:

[image: properties]

Then, you can access the button or textField in code behind and add click event for them.

You can read the document for more information :[how-the-ios-designer-works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/introduction?tabs=windows#how-the-ios-designer-works) and [storyboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/?tabs=windows)